# How to calculate a rolling median on only the first few rows using all the data? Attempting to quicken the script

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I am currently calculating a rolling medium for a dataframe in python. The script is run every 15 minutes and was taking to long to run for this time period. I only need to calculate the rolling median for the first few hours, but need to use 40 days worth of data.

Orginally I calculated the rolling median for the entire dataframe using the code below.

`df[column+'_ROLLING_MEDIAN']=df.groupby(grouping)[column].transform(lambda x:  x.rolling(window=window_size, min_periods=minimum, center=False).median())`

I attempted to pass my own method below to only calculate it for the first few hours, but it is running even longer then the rolling function.

#The df is sorted by time

```
def rolling_function_med(series):
     counter = 0
     for row_index in series.index:
         if row_index[2] >= day_cutoff:
             series[row_index] = series.iloc[counter:].median()
             counter+=1
         else:
             break
  series.iloc[counter+1:] = None
           
  return series

df[column+'_ROLLING_MEDIAN']=df.groupby(grouping)[column].transform(rolling_function_med )
```

Is there another way to achieve what I am attempting here, but it actually will make the code faster?

MRI Below:

```
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data = {'SERVICE_NAME': {0: 'Foo', 1: 'Foo', 2: 'Foo', 3: 'Foo', 4: 'Foo', 5: 'Foo', 6: 'Foo', 7: 'Foo', 8: 'Foo', 9: 'Foo', 10: 'Foo', 11: 'Foo', 12: 'Foo', 13: 'Foo', 14: 'Foo', 15: 'Foo', 16: 'Foo', 17: 'Foo', 18: 'Foo', 19: 'Foo', 20: 'Foo', 21: 'Foo', 22: 'Foo', 23: 'Foo', 24: 'Foo', 25: 'Foo', 26: 'Foo', 27: 'Foo', 28: 'Foo', 29: 'Foo', 30: 'Foo', 31: 'Foo', 32: 'Foo', 33: 'Foo', 34: 'Foo', 35: 'Foo', 36: 'Foo'}, 'HOUR': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0, 16: 0, 17: 0, 18: 0, 19: 0, 20: 0, 21: 0, 22: 0, 23: 0, 24: 0, 25: 0, 26: 0, 27: 0, 28: 0, 29: 0, 30: 0, 31: 0, 32: 0, 33: 0, 34: 0, 35: 0, 36: 0}, 'TRANSACTION_DATETIME_GROUPED_CST': {0: Timestamp('2023-08-21 00:15:00'), 1: Timestamp('2023-08-19 00:15:00'), 2: Timestamp('2023-08-18 00:15:00'), 3: Timestamp('2023-08-17 00:15:00'), 4: Timestamp('2023-08-16 00:15:00'), 5: Timestamp('2023-08-15 00:15:00'), 6: Timestamp('2023-08-14 00:15:00'), 7: Timestamp('2023-08-13 00:15:00'), 8: Timestamp('2023-08-12 00:15:00'), 9: Timestamp('2023-08-11 00:15:00'), 10: Timestamp('2023-08-10 00:15:00'), 11: Timestamp('2023-08-09 00:15:00'), 12: Timestamp('2023-08-08 00:15:00'), 13: Timestamp('2023-08-07 00:15:00'), 14: Timestamp('2023-08-06 00:15:00'), 15: Timestamp('2023-08-05 00:15:00'), 16: Timestamp('2023-08-04 00:15:00'), 17: Timestamp('2023-08-03 00:15:00'), 18: Timestamp('2023-08-01 00:15:00'), 19: Timestamp('2023-07-31 00:15:00'), 20: Timestamp('2023-07-30 00:15:00'), 21: Timestamp('2023-07-29 00:15:00'), 22: Timestamp('2023-07-28 00:15:00'), 23: Timestamp('2023-07-27 00:15:00'), 24: Timestamp('2023-07-26 00:15:00'), 25: Timestamp('2023-07-25 00:15:00'), 26: Timestamp('2023-07-24 00:15:00'), 27: Timestamp('2023-07-22 00:15:00'), 28: Timestamp('2023-07-21 00:15:00'), 29: Timestamp('2023-07-20 00:15:00'), 30: Timestamp('2023-07-19 00:15:00'), 31: Timestamp('2023-07-18 00:15:00'), 32: Timestamp('2023-07-17 00:15:00'), 33: Timestamp('2023-07-16 00:15:00'), 34: Timestamp('2023-07-15 00:15:00'), 35: Timestamp('2023-07-14 00:15:00'), 36: Timestamp('2023-07-13 00:15:00')}, 'MINUTE_GROUPING': {0: 15, 1: 15, 2: 15, 3: 15, 4: 15, 5: 15, 6: 15, 7: 15, 8: 15, 9: 15, 10: 15, 11: 15, 12: 15, 13: 15, 14: 15, 15: 15, 16: 15, 17: 15, 18: 15, 19: 15, 20: 15, 21: 15, 22: 15, 23: 15, 24: 15, 25: 15, 26: 15, 27: 15, 28: 15, 29: 15, 30: 15, 31: 15, 32: 15, 33: 15, 34: 15, 35: 15, 36: 15}, 'SUM_EXEC_TIME_IN_MILLIS_RATE': {0: 358.7777778, 1: 581.5848214, 2: 271.5, 3: 314.4285714, 4: 266.0, 5: 265.0, 6: 10369.33333, 7: 299.5, 8: 366.1428571, 9: 270.4285714, 10: 356.1666667, 11: 330.2575758, 12: 289.625, 13: 299.0, 14: 270.5, 15: 313.5, 16: 285.2272727, 17: 269.2413793, 18: 356.4444444, 19: 439.0, 20: 380.8709677, 21: 774.2, 22: 410.75, 23: 504.16, 24: 391.9166667, 25: 384.4, 26: 370.0, 27: 392.0, 28: 330.359375, 29: 294.3658537, 30: 316.125, 31: 334.6666667, 32: 411.0, 33: 520.0, 34: 306.3333333, 35: 420.5, 36: 322.0}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index(['SERVICE_NAME','HOUR','TRANSACTION_DATETIME_GROUPED_CST','MINUTE_GROUPING'])

min_time = min(df.index.get_level_values(level = 2))
day_cutoff =  (min_time + timedelta(days=40) - timedelta(hours=4))

def rolling_function_med(series):
    counter = 0
    for row_index in series.index:
        if row_index[2] >= day_cutoff:
             series[row_index] = series.iloc[counter:].median()
             counter+=1
        else:
            break
    series.iloc[counter+1:] = None
           
    return series

column = 'SUM_EXEC_TIME_IN_MILLIS_RATE'
grouping = ['SERVICE_NAME','HOUR', 'MINUTE_GROUPING']
df[column+'_ROLLING_MEDIAN']=df.groupby(grouping)[column].transform(rolling_function_med )

print(df)
```

Comment: Can you provide a (meaningful) minimal reproducible example of the data and the matching expected output?

Comment: For sure! Just give me one moment to replace some names. Thank You!

Comment: Pandas has a [rolling median](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.median.html#pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.median) function. Does this work for you?

Comment: The issue with rolling median is it calculates the rolling median for the entire column. I cannot limit with minimum bc the input size varies.

Comment: @mozway I have added the MRI to the post above!

Comment: @MichaelRunyan Can you please make the example a little bit clearer (shorter dataframe, with shorter window size where it's clear what should be computed). From the code the `day_cutoff=Timestamp('2023-08-21 20:15:00')` and the latest `TRANSACTION_DATETIME_GROUPED_CST` is `2023-08-21 00:15:00` so the `.median()` is never computed.  The `SUM_EXEC_TIME_IN_MILLIS_RATE_ROLLING_MEDIAN` contains only one value.